# how to display zero in cell when it is empty

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

in excel, how to display zero in cell when it is empty?

Comment: too little information.Include more details in your question like a business scenario, are you using OpenXML or something for excel manipulation, etc.

Comment: yes i am using openxml for excel manipulation. I want a cell should display zero when it is blank or empty, and when user enters some value it should take that value. If suppose user erases the value than again it should automatically display zero in cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a second sheet with a formula like `=IF(ISBLANK(A1),0,A1)` on all cells

Comment: this works but i want cell to retain the formula after insertion and deletion of data from it.

Comment: you need a vba macro then. an event handler http://blogs.msdn.com/b/project_programmability/archive/2007/02/12/vba-event-handler-example.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Set the value to `'0` instead of just `0`.

Comment: but when user enter value in that cell and again if he is erasing that values than cell should automatically show zero. it should not vanish the formula written in that cell

Comment: You should have listed that as part of your initial requirement :)